# Reading from the book of the Acts of the Apostles (3,13-15.17-19)

Tags: acts, historical-interpretation, sin, layers-of-meaning

> In those days, Peter told the people: “The God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob, the God of our fathers, has glorified his servant Jesus, whom you handed over and rejected before Pilate, when he had decided to release him. You rejected the saint, the just, and asked the pardon of a murderer; you killed the author of life, but God raised him from the dead, and we are witnesses. However, brothers, I know that you did it out of ignorance, and your authorities did the same; but God fulfilled in this way what he had said through the prophets, that his Messiah had to suffer. Therefore, repent and be converted, so that your sins may be blotted out. "

How can the last line of  this lecture be interpreted?

> Therefore, repent and be converted, so that your sins may be blotted out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your question about what it means for sins to be "blotted out"?

Comment: @curiousdannii no, it's about the complete statement.

Comment: Okay. Telling someone to repent is pretty straightforward, so I was guessing it was the last part that was prompting the question.

Comment: See also John 8:24.

Comment: @Lucian hmm ok. It'd be better had you said "it's related to this text due to..." heh:) I'm going to find a 'surprise' then.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore, repent and be converted, so that your sins may be blotted out.

If you repent and are converted, then your sins will be erased.

https://biblehub.com/commentaries/acts/3-19.htm Barnes' Notes on the Bible

> The expression to "blot out sins" is taken from the practice of creditors charging their debtors, and when the debt is paid, cancelling it, or wholly removing the record. The word used here properly refers to the practice of writing on tables covered with wax, and then by inverting the stylus, or instrument of writing, smoothing the wax again, and thus removing every trace of the record. This more entirely expresses the idea of pardoning than blotting does. It means wholly to remove the record, the charge, and every trace of the account against us. In this way God forgives sins.

Hebrews 8:12

> For I will forgive their wickedness and will remember their sins no more."

How can the last line of this lecture be interpreted?

It is the ultimate forgiveness.